# on click <input> select all value and copy to clipboard (cross browser support)

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, clipboard, selectall

I want to select all and copy to clipboard the value of input when the user clicks on the input itself with cross browser support.

Example:

onClick this:

```
<input value="Generated Value: www.google.com" />
```

it will SelectAll and copy the **Generated Value: www.google.com** to the clipboard

*I have tried a few jquery ready made scripts but i can't get them to work this way as they only work if the user clicks on a button or href link.*

Answer (score 1):

Check the javascript library `ZeroClipboard` at [davidwalsh.name/clipboard](http://davidwalsh.name/clipboard)

I hope it will help you :-)